# How get a collection of objects <edge, vertex> Neo4jClient .NET Cypher vs. C#

Tags: .net, neo4j, cypher, neo4jclient

```
    public IEnumerable<EdVeObj> Parse(string word)
    {
        var res = graphClient.Cypher.OptionalMatch($"(a{{name:'{word}'}})-[r]->(b)") 
        .Return((a, r, b) => new EdVeObj{RelUp = r.As<Edge>(), Target = b.<Vertex>()}).Results;            
        return res;
    }
    public class EdVeObj
    {                
        public Edge RelUp { get; set; }
        public Vertex Target { get; set; }
    }
```

I need to go through all the outgoing edges and get a collection of objects: the edge plus the vertex to which it comes.
Tell me please: how to perform this iteration?

Comment: The `Parse()` method gives you and [`IEnumerable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerable(v=vs.110).aspx), so you should simple get the result and iterate on it - e.g. with a foreach loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question isn't super clear, but as Gabor has mentioned, if you're looking to iterate through your results, you use `foreach`, i.e.:

```
var results = Parse("word");
foreach(var ev in results){
    //Do something with ev
}
```

You could equally use a `for` loop - but you'd need to `.ToList()` the results:

```
var results = Parse("word").ToList();
for(int i = 0; i < results.Count; i++){
    //Do something with results[i]
}
```

Your `cypher` would benefit from a bit of tuning, first off - there's no need to use `OptionalMatch` - you need the results to exist, if there's nothing there then it would return nothing anyway. Also - you really should be using a `label` of some variety, at the very least on the `a` node. You should also use `parameters` to get some more performance from the server.

I would change your code to:

```
public IEnumerable<EdVeObj> Parse(string word)
{
    var res = graphClient.Cypher
        .Match("(:YOUR_LABEL_HERE {name:$word})-[r]->(b)") 
        .WithParam("word", word)
        .Return((r, b) => new EdVeObj
            {
                RelUp = r.As<Edge>(), 
                Target = b.<Vertex>()
            })
        .Results;            

    return res;
}
```

On any big graph this is going to be pretty long running :/